# Ember Data LocalStorage Adapter find always rejected

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, local-storage

I am using ember data beta 11 with localstorage adapter version 0.4.0 ( also tested with 0.3.2), but when I try the find method it always goes into rejection when I use it with a query.

ex:
This works

```
this.store.find('segment');
```

but this does not work and always returns a rejected promise with its reason set to undefined

```
this.store.find('segment',{locked:false});
```

what could be the reason for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

Apparently the first answer wasn't the right one, but it cleared things up a bit, in Ember when you create a record, it is not saved to the `localstorage`, it is only cached in the store, so when you perform a find, it does find nothing because the storage did not store anything, so you need to also save the record.

Like so

```
var record = this.store.createRecord("model",hash);
record.save();
```

I wasn't doing `record.save()` which was the main cause of my problem.

For more info see [Ember:Persisting Records](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/persisting-records/)

Comment: i have the same problem when applying a query such as your {locked: false} case. but i don't believe adding a save is the correct solution. it will remedy the situation if you have records matching the query. if not then the find will fail. and usually localstorage will be empty on first use.

Answer (score 0):

(as stated in the comment) i have the same problem when applying a query such as your {locked: false} case. but i don't believe adding a save is the correct solution. it will remedy the situation if (and only if) you have records matching the query. if not then the find will fail -- for some reason. bearing in mind that localstorage will probably be empty on first use it becomes a problem.

if you check out http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-other-adapters/ the associated jsbin contains the following code for finding using the isCompleted boolean. it uses filter not find.

```
return this.store.filter('todo', function (todo) {
      return !todo.get('isCompleted');
    });
```

in your case i believe the following will suffice including on an empty localstorage

```
return this.store.filter('segment', function (todo) {
      return !todo.get('locked');
    });
```

---

heres a possibly better option. change the findQuery method of localstorage_adapter to return an empty array rather than a reject.

```
findQuery: function (store, type, query, recordArray) {
  var namespace = this._namespaceForType(type);
  var results = this.query(namespace.records, query);

  if (results.get('length')) {
    return this.loadRelationshipsForMany(type, results);
  } else {
    //return Ember.RSVP.reject();  Remove this
     **return Ember.RSVP.resolve([]); // Return an empty error not a 'reject'**
  }
},
```

Comment: it will suffice but because the find will look in the storage, will the filter will look into the loaded ember ones, find() results are always up to date, because find will always query the storage.

Comment: and with find you always need save, cause otherwise it won't create records in the store, but with filter() you only need `createRecord()`, filter also goes the same as `getById()` they all query the memory loaded data.